# how to replace polymorphism principle with templates to have a generic database?

Tags: c++, templates, vector, polymorphism, visual-studio-2019

So recently i learned some templates and even hared that it can replace polymorphism
when it comes to run time advantages as I've hared it beats polymorphism in that with the price of longer compilation time, is that true btw?

now let's get practical, let's say i have a vector of polymorphic game objects
with the base class of Game_Object :

```
Class Game_Object
{

public:

   Game_Object() = default;
   virtual ~Game_Object() = default;
   virtual void show() = 0;
   //----------- more functions here ---------//

 private:
        //----------- Members here ---------//
}
```

also i have a few derive classes, possibly derived of derived classes
like so:

```
Class Player : public Game_object
{
public:
   Player();
   virtual ~Player();
   virtual void show() override;
   //----------- more functions here ---------//

private:
    //----------- Members here ---------//
}
```

and here is an example of a class that derives twice:

first one is this inheritance:

```
Class Obstacle : public Game_object
    {
    public:
       Obstacle();
       virtual ~Obstacle();
       virtual void show() override;
       //----------- more functions here ---------//

    private:
        //----------- Members here ---------//
    }
```

and the second is this inheritance:

```
Class Wall : public Obstacle
    {
    public:
       Wall();
       virtual ~Wall();
       virtual void show() override;
       //----------- more functions here ---------//

    private:
        //----------- Members here ---------//
    }
```

now i hold these and more members in a vector like this:

```
std::vector<Game_Object*> m_objects:
```

or possibly even like this:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr< <Game_Object*> > m_objects:
```

**my question is, how do i make this generic database of game objects with templates?**

Comment: What is the "key" of you game objects?

Comment: i want an easy access to my game objects with a vector. like [item] for example or vec.at(item).

Comment: Still unclear what you are asking. Why doesn't `std::vector<std::unique_ptr< <Game_Object*> > m_objects:` work for you? It is just indexed by position in the list.

Comment: that will work, i just wanted a fester runtime so i wanted to use templates, maybe i should do something like so? std::vector<std::unique_ptr< <T*> > m_objects; and push back a Game_Object to it?